# RTK Query preventing caching of errors

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a form component that displays either a loading spinner, an error message or the queried data.

```
const UserForm = () => {
    const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useGetUserQuery()

    return isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
    ) : isError ? (
        <ErrorMessage error={error}/>
    ) : (
        <form>...</form>
    )
}
```

If the query encounters an error and then the component is unmounted and remounted, the error state is cached and the error message is briefly rendered before the query is fired again. On the initial render of the remounted component, `isError` is `true` and `isLoading` is `false`.

How could I prevent this behavior and not cache the error so that the initial render of the remounted component can show the spinner instead?

**Update**

The `usersApi` looks like this:

```
export const usersApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUser: build.query<User, number>({
      query: (id) => `users/${id}`,
      providesTags: (_result, _err, id) => [{ type: 'User', id }],
    }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: please add implementation of ```useGetUserQuery```

Comment: @AmirRezvani - this is a standard auto-generated query from a Redux Toolkit Query API definition.

Comment: you are following the Doc but if you read more about it u basically create your own query on ```createApi``` and then RTK query create that hook for you.

Comment: I mean how do you define your ```getUser ``` endpoint?